# PHPExcel not working on windows but works on Linux

Tags: php, opencart, phpexcel

I am using a extension of import/export products in OpenCart but there is an error when i used it on window.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not
>   open C:\Windows\Temp\php479C.tmp for reading! File does not exist.' in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\system\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:168
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\system\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(269):
>   PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->canRead('C:\Windows\Temp...') #1
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\system\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(207):
>   PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('C:\Windows\Temp...') #2
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\admin\model\catalog\productimportexport.php(1208):
>   PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify('C:\Windows\Temp...') #3
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\admin\controller\catalog\productimportexport.php(352):
>   ModelCatalogProductImportExport->upload('C:\Windows\Temp...', '1') #4
>   [internal function]: ControllerCatalogProductImportExport->bulk() #5
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\vqmod\ in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\system\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php
>   on line 168 Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'Could not open C:\Windows\Temp\php479C.tmp for reading! File does not
>   exist.' in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\system\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:168
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\system\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(269):
>   PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->canRead('C:\Windows\Temp...') #1
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\system\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(207):
>   PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('C:\Windows\Temp...') #2
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\admin\model\catalog\productimportexport.php(1208):
>   PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify('C:\Windows\Temp...') #3
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\admin\controller\catalog\productimportexport.php(352):
>   ModelCatalogProductImportExport->upload('C:\Windows\Temp...', '1') #4
>   [internal function]: ControllerCatalogProductImportExport->bulk() #5
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\vqmod\ in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\webwhisperer.com.au\watermark\system\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php
>   on line 168

Does anyone know what's the Problem here ..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The top of the stack trace tells you the answer:

```
Could not open C:\Windows\Temp\php479C.tmp for reading! File does not exist.
```

The PHPExcel class is unable to open that file as it does not exist. Looking at the stack trace, this is being uploaded by the 'upload' method of the ModelCatalogProductImportExport object. I would ensure that this function is correctly importing the file, and saving it to the correct directory before running the PHPExcel class functions over the file.